# How do I generate paylines and pay dots for a slot game?

Tags: architecture, game-mechanics, html5, browser-based-games

I'm working on a HTML5 slot game and am completely stuck on the pay lines and the dots that produce the lines from 1 end to the other.

What's the logic behind generating a random number of dots (9-30) and then paylines properly? Paylines shouldn't overlap each other. Similarly paydots shouldn't overlap and position themselves properly. On a small mobile screen 30 dots should just fit fine.

Then, how can I go about matching combinations from reels against the paylines?

Comment: This question seems vague. Can you edit your question to be a bit more specific?

Comment: Your pay lines are going to cross no matter what. Also the more lines you have the more likely they are to overlay each other (The company I work for primarily makes slot machines and their games). What you could do is check and see how many pay lines you already have over laying a reel symbol and use that count to offset draw to line position. Most likely you should have at least 2 * reelCount dots per line (a start and end for each reel symbol in the payline)

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson You should convert that comment to an answer, I think that pretty much covers it.

Answer (score 2):

For game shops dedicated to making slot machines, the manner in which a game pays out is determined by a staff of mathematicians dedicated to statistics.  In my experience (a single shop of about 25 people) the mathematicians were roughly equal in number to the programmers and artists.

Of course, this is true for a company making games headed to real casinos, where payouts need to be known with extreme accuracy.  They need that information both for selling their games to gambling businesses and for complying with local law.  *Your game* probably does not need such meticulous work.